# Vine unofficial API - How to get channels feeds

Tags: vine

There are a couple of Vine viewers online that have channel lists like the official site:

1 - https://bottlr.co/

[image]

2 - And another one:

[image]

And as far as I know, there still isn't an official Vine API. However, there is this unofficial way to get feeds:

http://khakimov.com/blog/2013/03/12/vines-undocumented-api/

It works for `popular` and `tags`, but there isn't an endpoint for `channels`. The `bottlr.co` channels follow the official `vine.co` channels exactly, but the `http://seenive.com/` channels don't.

1. I tried using the tags endpoint from the nameless API linked above, eg. `https://api.vineapp.com/timelines/tags/comedy`, but it doesn't match the official channel and it just pulls the most recent tagged media. I'm assuming the channels are curated and would like that feed.
2. I tried `https://api.vineapp.com/timelines/channels/comedy` on a guess but no luck.
3. I haven't tried scraping `vine.co`, which might be what `bottlr.com` does, but I'd rather not do that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a little late response here.. but i am the creator of https://bottlr.co and can give you the answers. We use the mobile app API, one way for you to get the endpoint can be by using Charles as a proxy on your mobile. The endpoints for channels are:

```
https://vine.co/api/timelines/channels/[name]/[area]
```

Where channels are in numbers:

```
            'comedy'                => 1,
            'art-and-experimental'  => 2,
            'nature'                => 5,
            'family'                => 7,
            'special-fx'            => 8,
            'sports'                => 9,
            'food'                  => 10,
            'music'                 => 11,
            'beauty-and-fashion'    => 12,
            'health-and-fitness'    => 13,
            'news-and-politics'     => 14,
            'animals'               => 17
```

And area can be popular or recent.

So an example to get the latest vines in comedy channel would be:

```
https://vine.co/api/timelines/channels/1/recent
```

Comment: How to get fixed number of vines like i want to get 10 vines and 10 more vines when user tap on load more button and so on ....??

Answer (score 0):

> https://api.vineapp.com/timelines/channels/**[channel_id]**/recent

This url returns (JSON format) the most recent vines added to the specific channel. 
[channel_id] should of course be changed accordingly.

1. Comedy
2. Art
3. ...

This was my solution to extract channel related Vines a while back. However, I don't know if this solution still holds.

Comment: "An unknown error occurred." -- No go at the moment. =(.

Comment: That is strange, if I surf to for example (https://api.vineapp.com/timelines/channels/2/recent) then I get just raw json data displayed in my browser. It can't be country-specific I suppose